# How to Read One signal notification if the App is not running in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

Actually I need to read those notification instead of tapping the notification banner.

I have used this code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {}
```

But this function only gets called when the app is in foreground or the notification banner gets tapped by the user.
I need bunch of code to read the code in Background. 
I am using OneSignal Push Notification service.

Comment: Have you find solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can able get the notification responce before notification banner shows. no need tap on notification banner.

```
 @available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    completionHandler([.sound, .alert, .badge])

    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

    alertRemoteNotification(notification.request.content.userInfo as NSDictionary
}
```